# Difference of Square root and order relation

Tags: inequality, radicals, gre-exam

If $a=\sqrt{15} -\sqrt{11}$, $b=\sqrt{27} - \sqrt{23}$, $c=\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{5}$ then which of the following is correct?

```
A. a>b>c
B. a>c>b
C. c>b>a
D. c>a>b
```

I am new to number system and don't want to calculate the square root to find out the answer. Is there any easy way to solve this?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-d}=\frac{d}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-d}}$.

So we have
$$a=\frac{4}{\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{11}}, b=\frac{4}{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt{23}}$$ 
Clearly $a>b$. As for $c$, although we have $d=1$, we can multiply both top and bottom by $4$ (for a like for like comparison), resuting in
$$c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{96}+\sqrt{80}}$$
which (given the sum of its denominator) is by far the smallest.

Comment: My bad..still not able to figure out....I got your hint. But how to apply here logically. If i understood, a has d=4, b has d=4 and c has d=1. Does it mean that c will be smallest and now we have to only compare a and b as both has same d?

Comment: I have had some more thoughts on my answer, and will edit accordingly.

Comment: Awesome...thanks for making it simple.

Answer (score 0):

The mean value theorem gives us that $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{2\sqrt{c}}$ for some $c$ between $a,b$. This lets you compare the first two, easily, since $a-b$ is the same for both cases.

Comment: We could compare the third one this way as well by multiplying by $\dfrac{2}{2}$

Comment: Which amounts to multiplying the RHS by $\frac{4}{4}$, yes. @PeterWoolfitt

Comment: Thanks Tom and Peter...got the logic.